# How to save and delete multiple String[] data in Android with SharedPreference?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and I would be glad if I can have some help here.
The problem I'm having right now is about the SharedPreference in android.  What I want to do is

- I want to save the ArrayList strings into Shared preference and keep appending to the      existing sharedpreference data with a comma like ( 123,23,56 ).
- I want to delete only the selected string data from the
  sharedpreference.

Currently, I tried to save string data and append to a single sharedpreference like the sample below

```
        public  String[] getStringList(Activity activity){
            String favoriteList = getStringFromPreferences(activity,null,"favorites");
            return convertStringToArray(favoriteList);
        }
        public  boolean putStringInPreferences(Activity activity,String nick,String key){
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(key, nick);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        public String getStringFromPreferences(Activity activity,String defaultValue,String key){
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String temp = sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
            return temp;
        }


        @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
        public void remover(Activity activity){
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
              editor.remove();
            //editor.clear();

            editor.commit();
            mainSwitch = false;
        }


        //method to convert string into array 
        private  String[] convertStringToArray(String str){
            String[] arr = str.split(",");
            return arr;
        }
```

I want to delete only a part of the string data ,however, the method remover() in the sample will delete all the data in the Sharedpreference so I was wondering how can I delete only a part of the selected data ? Or are there some better way save and manipulate data with Arrays ?

Comment: then use sqlite ... + ContetntProvider + Loaders ...

Answer (score 0):

according to this code you are removing all fields from sharedPreferences
in remover you need to get the string and replace it with the proper value.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String str = sharedPreferences.getString("myString");
str = str.replace("string to remove", "");

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("myString", str);
editor.commit();
```